# BulkInsert CSV file to table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

I've got some hard problems inserting my CSV file from a location into a table that will be used for making reports and data extraction matched with other data.

```
  Create table #PD_ABC (
  Column1
  Column2 etc etc
)

BULK INSERT #PD_ABC FROM  'F:\BulkInsert\Andrej\UtkastAntal(23)Export20141003.csv' 
WITH   (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',CODEPAGE = 'RAW',ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a')

insert into Maintenance.dbo.PD_ABC_Del1
select * from #PD_ABC
```

So far I supose everything should work. I made a similar script for .txt files but when comming to CSV somehow I cannot import them correctly.

This is the erros message I've been receving.

```
   Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PD_ABC_SP, Line 49
   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 3 (Gldnr).
```

No idea how to move forward from this.

Comment: what does the `Create Table` code look like in terms of data types?  You could open the CSV in excel and check the field lengths?

Comment: All the columns are varchar making it simple :)

Comment: but what length? `varcar(n)` ?

Comment: Varchar(250) Have checked it in excel a field is never longer than that amount of characters

Comment: comment out the line `insert into Maintenance.dbo.PD_ABC_Del1`, and see if you're successfully inserting into the temp table. If that works fine, then the **PD_ABC_Del1** table has a column which it too small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `Column3` doesn't have enough characters for data. Is `column3` type `char` or `varchar`? If so, you should give it more characters.